# access root element of react component

Tags: reactjs

If I have the following in the `render()` function of my react component

```
return <div ref="myId"></div>;
```

I know I can access the div element in my react code with `this.refs.myId`.  But if the ref attribute were not defined in the div element, is there another way for me get a handle on the div element since it is a **root element** of the component?

Answer (score 26):

You can get the root element for a component using `ReactDOM` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom) `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)`

Answer (score 7):

The answer above has been deprecated in favor of using the `forwardRef` attribute. Now there should be a mechanism (meaning you have to create it) for forwarding the root node to the parent using the forwardRef function as shown below

```
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));

// You can now get a ref directly to the DOM button:
const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton ref={ref}>Click me!</FancyButton>;
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html